# Use knockout.js in catalog page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, catalog, knockoutjs

We are developing an extension for configurable products which provides the following functionality on product page.

On the product view page of the configurable product, when the customer finishes the selection of the config options, the product detail and sku should change just like the media is changing. 
I tried to trace this from the functionality implemented in checkout but i got more confused by doing this.

Can anybody tell what is the procedure to use the ko.js in magento frontend?